# Array List With Custom Object Reorder

Tags: android, arraylist

I have one `ArrayList<MediaItem>` In Media Item there is one `Boolean` Field named **IsDownloaded**

I want a loop that can sort items by **IsDownloaded**  filed from true to false.

Comment: before anything please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
int ff = 0; // First false index
  CustomObject pf = list.get(0); // photo with false

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
    CustomObject p = list.get(i);
    if (p. IsDownloaded())
    {
      // Replace it with the current photo with false
      list.set(i, pf);
      // Put the selected photo in place of the first false photo (and move this index)
      list.set(ff++, p);
      // Next photo is the next to swap (might also advance ff up to the next unselected photo)
      pf = list.get(ff);
    }
  }



for (CustomObject p : list) {
    println(p.selected + "," + p.index);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Its Worked.